# Postgresql "+" symbol for carriage return / new line for zsh script

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, rss, zsh

So I query that pulls text from a column called "description."

Each description contains a list like so:

```
1) Some text here
2) Some text here
3) Some text here
```

The problem is when I run the query in my zsh script the new lines return a "+" symbol instead of a carriage return.

```
1) Some text here + 2) Some text here + 3) Some text here...
```

The code is

```
tempdescriptionday4=$(/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/psql -h 1.1.1.1 -p5555 -U myuser mytable -t -c "SELECT description FROM cycle_10 WHERE air_date = 2020-11-10"
```

I'm trying to inject this list into an XML file for an RSS feed but I'm stuck on how to format this properly. I tried replacing the + symbol with 
 but that didn't work--I still am not getting a new line. Any ideas?

Comment: The newlines will be preserved - there must be something you are not telling us that strips them from `tempdescriptionday4`. You may want to use the `-A` option of `psql` to get rid of the `+`.

Comment: @nwood21 : I wouldn't expect carriage returns in the output of this query anyway, unless perhaps your `psql` is a native Windows application. I would expect that the result set is separated by _newline_ characters. If you do not store the output into a variable, but just let stdout go to your terminal, do you still get everything in one line?

Answer (score 1):

Found this in the postgresql12 manual — it's called:**linestyle**

"Sets the border line drawing style to one of ascii, old-ascii, or unicode. Unique abbreviates are allowed. (that would mean one letter is enough.) The default setting is ascii. This option only affects the aligned and wrapped output formats"

So for me since I have multiple lines in a cell it "wraps" the text at the end making it a wrapped output format.

"ascii style uses plain ASCII characters. Newlines in data are shown using a + symbol in the right-hand margin." When the wrapped format wraps data from one line to the next without a new line character, a dot"." is shown in in the right-hand margin of the first line, and again in the left-hand margin of the following line."

There's also "old-ascii" style that uses a ":" for wrapping and a "unicode" style which uses an ellipsis symbol in the right and margin of first line.

So the problem I have is that the *output format* is using ASCII by default when there's no available option for XML output style for new lines. Bummer.

Turning linestyle *off* fixes removing the + symbol but I want the outputted linestyle to be XML so if it strips any new line indication there's no way for me to format it. "-A --no-align Switches to unaligned output mode. (The default output mode is aligned.) This is equivalent to \pset format unaligned."

So I used awk to substitute the + symbol for 
 and also tried 
 but those are not creating new lines for me? It validates as proper XML.